# Sort mutidimensional array by values total

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I am trying to sort multidimensional array by values total in php.

`[
c => [1=>22, 2=> 14, 3=> 55],
a => [7=> 33, 2=> 19, 51=> 43, 14=> 27],
...
]`

since values total of a subarray are higher than in c, it should be first in this example.
I would appreciate very much help regarding this problem.

Comment: `uasort($arr, function($a, $b) { return  array_sum($b) - array_sum($a);});`

Comment: Perhaps this page can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33720295/php-sort-array-by-arraysum-of-this

Comment: @splash58 i tried but it is not working, even the array keys (a,c) are not kept.

Comment: I've update the comment, try now

Comment: @Thefourthbird this function does sort properly, but array keys are not kept.

Comment: @splash58 thanks a lot, that is what i was searching for.

Answer (score 0):

As @splash58 comment (just to make formal answer):

Use [`uasort`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.uasort.php)() and [`array_sum`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php) as:

```
uasort($arr, function($a, $b) { return array_sum($b) - array_sum($a);});
```

Live example: [3v4l](https://3v4l.org/F89ng)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `array_multisort` with `array_map`

```
array_multisort(array_map(function($v){return array_sum($v);},$a), SORT_DESC, $a);
```

First argument with `array_map` is the sum of the all sub-array. You can change the order of the result array by modifying the 2nd argument `SORT_ASC`, `SORT_DESC`

Working example : https://3v4l.org/4fpXh